# Multiple select drop down query in database

Tags: c#, sql, database, asp.net-mvc-4, filter

I make ASP.NET MVC 4 web application. I have web page, that show lists of devices. I want to make filter with multiple select drop down and to take selected elements from database.
Lets for example I have list of Devices, that I take as IEnumerable from database. In other hand I have list of selected values.
Before I make that structure I have single select drop down and next filter expression

```
list = list.Where(device => device.Value == filter.Value);
```

Now with list in filter I don't know how to write expression.

Edit: I can make simple foreach of devices and add are values that meet conditions in new list. But I don't like this decision, because don't look well as lambda. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use select query, like sql.

For example, you have a list with devices(`devices`) and selected list devices id from dropdownlist(`selectedDevices`).

Try this:

```
var result = from device in devices
             join selectedDevice in selectedDevices on device.ID equals selectedDevice
             select device;
```